# Magento 2: Import with required attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, import, csv

[image]

If I want to import products via csv-file I need to have all the required attributes as columns in my csv-file right?

**Can anyone tell me what the attributes 'price_type', 'price_view','shipment_type','sku_type' and 'weight_type'(in the image) mean and where I can find more information(reference) on them ?**

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage your csv attribute type from Admin panel.

Go To admin.

```
Store -> Attributes -> Product
```

[image]

Now click on your extra attributes link one by one which are not used to import in csv,  **

> Set Required Field To No

Now you dont required to add those extra attributes.

Now You can import using csv with your custom attribute values.

You have given list of attributes on your questions are related to Bundle proudcts.

Comment: can we dot it from programmatically while uploading CSV file?